# Endless wifi disconnects/reconnects

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm watching `/var/log/syslog` because my Internet browsing experience is miserable.

I've ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure I'm as up to date as possible. This cycle starting with wpa_supplicant and ending with sent link up event happens about once every 20 seconds.

```
May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 wpa_supplicant[1148]: wlx7cdd90841db3:
SME: Trying to authenticate with 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed
(SSID='iitLpys1a0-2G' freq=2412 MHz)   

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.317494] wlx7cdd90841db3:
authenticate with 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed     May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2
NetworkManager[986]: <info>  [1496153077.8055] device
(wlx7cdd90841db3): supplicant interface state: scanning ->
authenticating  

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 wpa_supplicant[1148]: wlx7cdd90841db3:
Trying to associate with 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed (SSID='iitLpys1a0-2G'
freq=2412 MHz)  May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.356831]
wlx7cdd90841db3: send auth to 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed (try 1/3) 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.359926] wlx7cdd90841db3:
authenticated May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.360708]
wlx7cdd90841db3: associate with 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed (try 1/3) 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 NetworkManager[986]: <info> 
[1496153077.8119] device (wlx7cdd90841db3): supplicant interface
state: authenticating -> associating 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.367097] wlx7cdd90841db3:
RX AssocResp from 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=4) 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK:
name:wlx7cdd90841db3 index:3 flags:0x00011003 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK:
name:wlx7cdd90841db3 index:3 flags:0x00011003 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 wpa_supplicant[1148]: wlx7cdd90841db3:
Associated with 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.375653] wlx7cdd90841db3:
associated 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 NetworkManager[986]: <info> 
[1496153077.8276] device (wlx7cdd90841db3): supplicant interface
state: associating -> associated 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 NetworkManager[986]: <info> 
[1496153077.9244] device (wlx7cdd90841db3): supplicant interface
state: associated -> 4-way handshake

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 wpa_supplicant[1148]: wlx7cdd90841db3:
WPA: Key negotiation completed with 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed [PTK=CCMP
GTK=CCMP] 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 wpa_supplicant[1148]: wlx7cdd90841db3:
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 6c:b0:ce:b4:5b:ed completed [id=0
id_str=] 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK:
name:wlx7cdd90841db3 index:3 flags:0x00011043 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK:
name:wlx7cdd90841db3 index:3 flags:0x00011043 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 vmnetBridge: Adding interface
wlx7cdd90841db3 index:3 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 vmnetBridge: Started bridge
wlx7cdd90841db3 to virtual network 0. 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.489695] /dev/vmnet: open
called by PID 1402 (vmnet-bridge) 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.489707] /dev/vmnet: hub 0
does not exist, allocating memory. 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.489726] /dev/vmnet: port
on hub 0 successfully opened 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [
 2063.489736] bridge-wlx7cdd90841db3: device is wireless, enabling SMAC 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.489739]
bridge-wlx7cdd90841db3: up 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [
 2063.489743] bridge-wlx7cdd90841db3: attached 

May 30 09:04:37 osr-ubuntu-2 NetworkManager[986]: <info> 
[1496153077.9402] device (wlx7cdd90841db3): supplicant interface
state: 4-way handshake -> completed 

May 30 09:04:38 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [ 2063.689907] userif-3: sent
link down event. 

May 30 09:04:38 osr-ubuntu-2 kernel: [
 2063.689912] userif-3: sent link up event.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04? It does have known issues with USB wireless devices

Comment: 16.04 is my version, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the router and wifi, then rebooting the machine seems to have cleared it up.